# Converted hex formats

Tags: hex

I have a hex value that is in the format:

```
0x00000000:0x00000000:0x00000000:0x00000000
```

I need to convert it to a format like:

```
00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
```

I was hoping to be able to strip the 0x's and insert colons every two characters but that does not seem to be correct. How can I convert these two formats?

Comment: Is this a big / little endian issue with the register system you are using for large numbers, or are you working with pure strings?  If I had to guess, this is one of these in which you look at it, say "duh", slap yourself on the forehead and then delete the whole question"

Comment: The thing is, I'm not sure. I am getting the first format from a hardware manufacturer but the software protocol I am using requires the second format. I tried an approach similar to the one posted by @AaronD but it does not work. I thought that perhaps there is an intricacy to hexidecimal formats I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Is it possible the original #'s are in binary?  11111111 (base 2) = 255 (base 10) = FF (base 16)

Comment: no, the example i gave is all zeros but the seeds i am actually working with have letters a-f in them.

Comment: What language would you like to work in?  (hint... I'm thinking your incoming data is real hex, so you need to convert that to a string, then convert that to a different string.  In the alternative, import the data convert from binary to hex to string...)  It would be nice to know the specific nature of your errors as well as the format of the original data.  Hint: You've got 6857 points on stack overflow.  I suspect you know how this stuff works?

Comment: What do you mean by "real hex" as opposed to a string, @zipzit? The errors I'm getting are not super helpful, unfortunately- I'm working with bluetooth firmware here so it either works or it doesn't. The language I'm working in is java.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely with strings.  In C#:

```
    string original = "0x00000000:0x00000000:0x00000000:0x00000000";

    //remove the unwanted characters
    string[] split = { "0x", ":" };
    split = original.Split(split, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    //format the rest in 2-char chunks
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < split[i].Length; j += 2)
        {
            result += split[i].Substring(j, 2) + ":";
        }
    }

    //remove the trailing ':'
    result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
```

Error handling omitted for clarity.

Is this helpful?

Comment: Mods, please move this to the active comment thread; I don't have enough rep yet to put it there directly. | @Keller: How does it not work?  Compiler errors?  Runtime errors?  Wrong formatting?  Since they were all indistinguishable zeros, I assumed that all the nybbles were in the same order as stated, so it very well could be the wrong endian.  Could you re-post the example with random data?